# What is the most succinct way to remove the first character from a string in Swift?

Tags: string, swift

I want to delete the first character from a string. So far, the most succinct thing I've come up with is:

```
display.text = display.text!.substringFromIndex(advance(display.text!.startIndex, 1))
```

I know we can't index into a string with an `Int` because of Unicode, but this solution seems awfully verbose. Is there another way that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Actually you can avoid the whole `advance` thing by casting `display.text!` to NSString. I'm not saying that's a good solution - just correcting a possible misconception. With NSString, you _can_ index into it with Int. - And the reason you can't index with Int is not because of Unicode; it's because a Character can consist of multiple compound codepoints.

Comment: If your doing this in order to capitalise the `String` then Swift 3 has introduced the `capitalized` function to `String`.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

If you're using **Swift 3**, you can ignore the second section of this answer. Good news is, this is now actually succinct again! Just using String's new remove(at:) method.

```
var myString = "Hello, World"
myString.remove(at: myString.startIndex)

myString // "ello, World"
```

---

I like the global `dropFirst()` function for this.

```
let original = "Hello" // Hello
let sliced = dropFirst(original) // ello
```

It's short, clear, and works for anything that conforms to the Sliceable protocol.

**If you're using Swift 2**, this answer has changed. You can still use dropFirst, but not without dropping the first character from your strings `characters` property and then converting the result back to a String. dropFirst has also become a method, not a function.

```
let original = "Hello" // Hello
let sliced = String(original.characters.dropFirst()) // ello
```

Another alternative is to use the suffix function to splice the string's `UTF16View`. Of course, this has to be converted back to a String afterwards as well.

```
let original = "Hello" // Hello
let sliced = String(suffix(original.utf16, original.utf16.count - 1)) // ello
```

All this is to say that the solution I originally provided has turned out not to be the most succinct way of doing this in newer versions of Swift. I recommend falling back on @chris' solution using `removeAtIndex()` if you're looking for a short and intuitive solution.

```
var original = "Hello" // Hello
let removedChar = original.removeAtIndex(original.startIndex)

original // ello
```

And as pointed out by @vacawama in the comments below, another option that doesn't modify the original String is to use substringFromIndex.

```
let original = "Hello" // Hello
let substring = original.substringFromIndex(advance(original.startIndex, 1)) // ello
```

Or if you happen to be looking to drop a character off the beginning and end of the String, you can use substringWithRange. Just be sure to guard against the condition when `startIndex + n > endIndex - m`.

```
let original = "Hello" // Hello

let newStartIndex = advance(original.startIndex, 1)
let newEndIndex = advance(original.endIndex, -1)

let substring = original.substringWithRange(newStartIndex..<newEndIndex) // ell
```

The last line can also be written using subscript notation.

```
let substring = original[newStartIndex..<newEndIndex]
```

Comment: And it doesn't require you to step into the Foundation world.

Comment: And it is very much swift/fp.

Comment: Thanks, that's much more elegant. I've been programming in Objective C for years and am taking the iTunes U Stanford iOS programming course in Swift. I still have lots to learn about the new paradigm.

Comment: Keep in mind while using dropLast or dropFirst, unwrap the string otherwise it'll not work.

Comment: I think that the advance function is no longer used.

Comment: Great answer! I think it's worth noting the return value of the `remove(at:)` method: it's the character removed, not the new string. For example, `let removedCharacter = myString.remove(at: myString.startIndex)`. I was making the mistake of returning the result of the method call, forgetting that this was the case in this approach. Happy coding all!

Answer (score 160):

**Update for Swift 4**

In Swift 4, `String` conforms to `Collection` again, so it is possible to use `dropFirst` and `dropLast` to trim the beginnings and ends of strings.  The result is of type `Substring`, so you need to pass that to the `String` constructor to get back a `String`:

```
let str = "hello"
let result1 = String(str.dropFirst())    // "ello"
let result2 = String(str.dropLast())     // "hell"
```

`dropFirst()` and `dropLast()` also take an `Int` to specify the number of characters to drop:

```
let result3 = String(str.dropLast(3))    // "he"
let result4 = String(str.dropFirst(4))   // "o"
```

If you specify more characters to drop than are in the string, the result will be the empty string (`""`).

```
let result5 = String(str.dropFirst(10))  // ""
```

---

**Update for Swift 3**

If you just want to remove the first character and want to change the original string in place, then see @MickMacCallum's answer.  If you want to create a new string in the process, use `substring(from:)`.  With an extension to `String`, you can hide the ugliness of `substring(from:)` and `substring(to:)` to create useful additions to trim the start and ends of a `String`:

```
extension String {
    func chopPrefix(_ count: Int = 1) -> String {
        return substring(from: index(startIndex, offsetBy: count))
    }

    func chopSuffix(_ count: Int = 1) -> String {
        return substring(to: index(endIndex, offsetBy: -count))
    }
}

"hello".chopPrefix()    // "ello"
"hello".chopPrefix(3)   // "lo"

"hello".chopSuffix()    // "hell"
"hello".chopSuffix(3)   // "he"
```

Like `dropFirst` and `dropLast` before them, these functions will crash if there aren't enough letters available in the String.  The onus is on the caller to use them properly.  This is a valid design decision.  One could write them to return an optional which then would have to be unwrapped by the caller.

---

**Swift 2.x**

Alas in **Swift 2**, `dropFirst` and `dropLast` (the previous best solution) aren't as convenient as they were before.  With an extension to `String`, you can hide the ugliness of `substringFromIndex` and `substringToIndex`:

```
extension String {
    func chopPrefix(count: Int = 1) -> String {
         return self.substringFromIndex(advance(self.startIndex, count))
    }

    func chopSuffix(count: Int = 1) -> String {
        return self.substringToIndex(advance(self.endIndex, -count))
    }
}

"hello".chopPrefix()    // "ello"
"hello".chopPrefix(3)   // "lo"

"hello".chopSuffix()    // "hell"
"hello".chopSuffix(3)   // "he"
```

Like `dropFirst` and `dropLast` before them, these functions will crash if there aren't enough letters available in the String.  The onus is on the caller to use them properly.  This is a valid design decision.  One could write them to return an optional which then would have to be unwrapped by the caller.

---

In **Swift 1.2**, you'll need to call `chopPrefix` like this:

```
"hello".chopPrefix(count: 3)  // "lo"
```

or you can add an underscore `_` to the function definitions to suppress the parameter name:

```
extension String {
    func chopPrefix(_ count: Int = 1) -> String {
         return self.substringFromIndex(advance(self.startIndex, count))
    }

    func chopSuffix(_ count: Int = 1) -> String {
        return self.substringToIndex(advance(self.endIndex, -count))
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still blown away by how complicated Swift's built-in string manipulation is. I mean this is basic, basic stuff; it should not look like I'm implementing a parser. Thanks for the extension to simplify this. It's baffling Apple wouldn't just add this to the String class! Maybe it's still in a lot of flux.

Comment: This is what they call "evolution" kids. It would be hilarious if we didn't have to deal with it every day. I know there are reasons for the String API being the way it is but, really truly, this must put off so many potential converts to this language. The previous commenter is absolutely right - this should be basic, basic stuff.

Comment: @devios1 Agreed; Swift is a very elegant language but Apple really dropped the ball here.

Answer (score 18):

Depends on what what you want the end result to be (mutating vs nonmutating).

As of Swift 4.1:

**Mutating:**

```
var str = "hello"
str.removeFirst() // changes str
```

**Nonmutating:**

```
let str = "hello"
let strSlice = str.dropFirst() // makes a slice without the first letter
let str2 = String(strSlice)
```

**Notes:**

- I put an extra step in the `nonmutating` example for clarity. Subjectively,  combining the last two steps would be more succinct.
- The naming of `dropFirst` seems a bit odd to me because if  I am understanding the [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#strive-for-fluent-usage) correctly, `dropFirst` should really be something like `droppingFirst` because it is nonmutating. Just a thought :).

Comment: indeed, it should be `droppingFirst` - they messed up!

Answer (score 17):

**Swift 2.2**

> 'advance' is unavailable: call the 'advancedBy(n)' method on the index

```
    func chopPrefix(count: Int = 1) -> String {
        return self.substringFromIndex(self.startIndex.advancedBy(count))
    }

    func chopSuffix(count: Int = 1) -> String {
        return self.substringFromIndex(self.endIndex.advancedBy(count))
    }
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
    func chopPrefix(_ count: Int = 1) -> String {
        return self.substring(from: self.characters.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: count))
    }

    func chopSuffix(_ count: Int = 1) -> String {
       return self.substring(to: self.characters.index(self.endIndex, offsetBy: -count))
    }
```

**Swift 3.2**

> A view of the string's contents as a collection of characters.
>
> ```
> @available(swift, deprecated: 3.2, message: "Please use String or Substring directly")
> public var characters: String.CharacterView
> ```

```
func chopPrefix(_ count: Int = 1) -> String {
    if count >= 0 && count <= self.count {
        return self.substring(from: String.Index(encodedOffset: count))
    }
    return ""
}

func chopSuffix(_ count: Int = 1) -> String {
    if count >= 0 && count <= self.count {
        return self.substring(to: String.Index(encodedOffset: self.count - count))
    }
    return ""
}
```

**Swift 4**

```
extension String {

    func chopPrefix(_ count: Int = 1) -> String {
        if count >= 0 && count <= self.count {
            let indexStartOfText = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: count)
            return String(self[indexStartOfText...])
        }
        return ""
    }

    func chopSuffix(_ count: Int = 1) -> String {
        if count >= 0 && count <= self.count {
            let indexEndOfText = self.index(self.endIndex, offsetBy: -count)
            return String(self[..<indexEndOfText])
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you forgot to add the negation -count to the chopSuffix function

Answer (score 12):

In Swift 2, do this:

```
let cleanedString = String(theString.characters.dropFirst())
```

I recommend https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-06-why-is-swifts-string-api-so-hard.html to get an understanding of Swift strings.

Answer (score 7):

The previous answers are pretty good, but as of today, I think this may be the most succinct way to remove the first character from a string in **Swift 4**:

```
var line: String = "This is a string..."
var char: Character? = nil

char = line.removeFirst()

print("char = \(char)")  // char = T
print("line = \(line)")  // line = his is a string ...
```

Answer (score 6):

What about this?

```
s.removeAtIndex(s.startIndex)
```

This of course assumes that your string is mutable. It returns the character which has been removed, but alters the original string.

Answer (score 1):

I know of nothing more succinct out of the box, but you could easily implement prefix `++`, e.g.,

```
public prefix func ++ <I: ForwardIndexType>(index: I) -> I {
    return advance(index, 1)
}
```

After which you can use it to your heart's content very succinctly:

```
str.substringFromIndex(++str.startIndex)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 2 use this String extension:

```
extension String
{
    func substringFromIndex(index: Int) -> String
    {
        if (index < 0 || index > self.characters.count)
        {
            print("index \(index) out of bounds")
            return ""
        }
        return self.substringFromIndex(self.startIndex.advancedBy(index))
    }
}

display.text = display.text!.substringFromIndex(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

> "en_US,fr_CA,es_US".chopSuffix(5).chopPrefix(5) // ",fr_CA,"

```
extension String {
    func chopPrefix(count: Int = 1) -> String {
        return self.substringFromIndex(self.startIndex.advancedBy(count))
    }

    func chopSuffix(count: Int = 1) -> String {
        return self.substringToIndex(self.endIndex.advancedBy(-count))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift3

```
extension String {
    func chopPrefix(_ count: UInt = 1) -> String {
        return substring(from: characters.index(startIndex, offsetBy: Int(count)))
    }

    func chopSuffix(_ count: UInt = 1) -> String {
        return substring(to: characters.index(endIndex, offsetBy: -Int(count)))
    }
}

class StringChopTests: XCTestCase {
    func testPrefix() {
        XCTAssertEqual("original".chopPrefix(0), "original")
        XCTAssertEqual("Xfile".chopPrefix(), "file")
        XCTAssertEqual("filename.jpg".chopPrefix(4), "name.jpg")
    }

    func testSuffix() {
        XCTAssertEqual("original".chopSuffix(0), "original")
        XCTAssertEqual("fileX".chopSuffix(), "file")
        XCTAssertEqual("filename.jpg".chopSuffix(4), "filename")
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should add a test where the input is in a negative value

Answer (score 0):

**To remove first character from string**

```
let choppedString = String(txtField.text!.characters.dropFirst())
```

Comment: @JasonFoglia i don't know that you give down vote or not. if you give down vote then can you please explain in detail.

Comment: I re-checked this and found that it is correct. I edited the answer so I can properly vote up on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **Swift4** crash save version of the `chopPrefix` extension, leaving `chopSuffix` to the community ...

```
extension String {
    func chopPrefix(_ count: Int = 1) -> String {
        return count>self.count ? self : String(self[index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: count)...])
    }
 }
```