# Remove the first six characters from a String (Swift)

Tags: swift, string, character

What's the best way to go about removing the first six characters of a string? Through Stack Overflow, I've found a couple of ways that were supposed to be solutions but I noticed an error with them. For instance,

```
extension String {
func removing(charactersOf string: String) -> String {
    let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
    let components = self.components(separatedBy: characterSet)
    return components.joined(separator: "")
}
```

If I type in a website like `https://www.example.com`, and store it as a variable named website, then type in the following

```
website.removing(charactersOf: "https://")
```

it removes the `https://` portion but it also removes all h's, all t's, :'s, etc. from the text.

How can I just delete the first characters?

Comment: Use `if str.length >= 6 { let newstr = str.chopPrefix(6) }`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30829999/1630618

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`length` is the number of characters you want to remove (6 in your case)

```
extension String {

  func toLengthOf(length:Int) -> String {
            if length <= 0 {
                return self
            } else if let to = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: length, limitedBy: self.endIndex) {
                return self.substring(from: to)

            } else {
                return ""
            }
        }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: have you tried emojis? 
"‍‍‍".toLengthOf(length: 1)
will be "‍"

Comment: @Kubba This works for emojis as well. In your case, the output would be "".

Comment: after your edits - now it outputs: `"12".toLengthOf(length: 1) // 2`, `"‍‍‍".toLengthOf(length: 1) // "‍‍"`

Comment: @Kubba I have added the screen shot of your scenario. Please have a look.

Comment: use emoji which is made from more than emoji. For example  is made from one emoji. ‍‍‍ is made from four basic emojis. `"\u{200D}\u{200D}\u{200D}" == "‍‍‍" //true`

Comment: because  is a single emoji, ‍‍‍ is not, try with it.

Comment: @Kubba This won't work for emojis made from more than one emojis because a normal emoji would contain only one character whereas the one you mentioned contains multiples characters.
But I think it will work for the scenario asked in the question.

Comment: Getting a warning as 'substring(from:) is deprecated.'

Answer (score 59):

In Swift 4 it is really simple, just use `dropFirst(n: Int)`

```
let myString = "Hello World"
myString.dropFirst(6)
//World
```

In your case: `website.dropFirst(6)`

Comment: I had to make a new String and pass the result of `dropFirst` to its constructor to make it compile.

Answer (score 35):

Why not :

```
let stripped = String(website.characters.dropFirst(6))
```

Seems more concise and straightforward to me.

(it won't work with multi-char emojis either mind you)

[EDIT] Swift 4 made this even shorter:

```
let stripped = String(website.dropFirst(6))
```

Comment: Awesome, After lots of R&D i've found best required sollution thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

It will remove first 6 characters from a string

```
    var str = "Hello-World"
    let range1 = str.characters.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 6)..<str.endIndex
    str = str[range1]
    print("the end time is : \(str)")
```