# Extract substring from URL string

Tags: swift, swift3

I have the following URL string:

> eventid=VSl4WcedBNbjqgXe7bzQCw&timestamp=1501047125&status=ok&ldpj=-23&author=Al+Jazeera+Arabic+قناة+الجزيرة&ptchn=fiwzLy-8yKzIbsmZTzxDgw&live_chunk_readahead=3&video_id=fN2sEo7hq-E&allow_ratings=0&allow_embed=1&token=vThp8hY3AuC-jibt_jf7TEzWnuqUY7oImICFXKxkWbM=&plid=AAVVMcSvP1Tr6SGM&partnerid=27&of=sjG7v9N-R2P9uySMx2Af7Q&live_default_broadcast=1&watermark=,https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/watermark/youtube_watermark-vflHX6b6E.png,https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/watermark/youtube_hd_watermark-vflAzLcD6.png&streaminglib_module=1&live_storyboard_spec=https://i.ytimg.com/sb/fN2sEo7hq-E/storyboard_live_60_3x3_b0/M$M.jpg?rs=AOn4CLBoEYL8Dt3Yf1HhjHlpNUAc4jqmSg#106#60#3#3&video_verticals=[881,+397]&csn=VSl4WcedBNbjqgXe7bzQCw&muted=0&length_seconds=1800&hlsdvr=1&videostats_playback_base_url=[https://s.youtube.com&title=Al+Jazeera+Arabic+Live+Stream+HD-+البث+الحي+لقناة+الجزيرة+الإخبارية+بجودة+عالية&ptk=aljazeera&iurl=https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fN2sEo7hq-E/hqdefault_live.jpg&vm=CAEQARgE&hlsvp=https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/hls_variant/gcr/us/signature/26ADA228BD5549EC76852E925945A6EDBD8A78A9.268E76E7A0831E0DB3C36670FCA24805B0F9AD94/requiressl/yes/source/yt_live_broadcast/key/yt6/ip/72.239.175.191/ipbits/0/maudio/1/playlist_type/DVR/itag/0/expire/1501068725/sparams/gcr,go,id,ip,ipbits,itag,maudio,playlist_type,requiressl,source,expire/go/1/id/fN2sEo7hq-E.0/file/index.m3u8&pltype=contentlive&cl=162900125&iurlmq=https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fN2sEo7hq-E/mqdefault_live.jpg&enable_cardio_before_playback=1&no_get_video_log=1&short_view_count_text=3M+views&avg_rating=4.24240619416&fexp=9422596,9431012,9434289,9441392,9446364,9449243,9457141,9460072,9461821,9463594,9464546,9465833,9466793,9466795,9466797,9466851,9467217,9468797,9468799,9468805,9471755,9475953,9477113,9477691,9478524,9478670,9480034,9480475,9480535,9480795,9481684,9482647,9483080,9484209,9484514,9484643,9484706,9485999&keywords=al+jazeera+tv,al+jazeera+Arabic,الجزيره,اخبار,خبر,free+tv+channels,aljazira,اخبار+الجزيرة,الاسكندرية,الجزيرة+مصر+مباشر,al+jazeera+english+live,aljazeera+tv+live,داعش,العراق,اخبار+العراق,اخبار+سوريا,دمشق,اخبار+مصر,سوريا,بشار+الاسد,عاجل+ليبيا,عاجل,الحصاد,النشرة,نشرة,الاخبار,الاهرام,الوفد,الجزيرة+مباشر,الجمهورية,syria+news,البث+الحي,البث+الحي+لقناة+الجزيرة,جودة+عالية,hd&idpj=-4&c=WEB&innertube_client_version=1.20170718&account_playback_token=QUFFLUhqa3NJenBCUUNnZnBtMHdOb3FLSWE0cG9qQkZBZ3xBQ3Jtc0ttYkdZeEI0TExmQWo1RldLQlFZSGtLTE1wcEJGamNNZnE4UlhDaUpfRGtvSG5WbG1KUHNvbk44T2dtM2NRb0NwWmNZaU9sdGc2MTY3QUg3SldKTmtxOWNzMjVfZ0R5VDYwM1E3RDVQQnNHTU12OVphSQ==&iv3_module=1&iurlhq=https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fN2sEo7hq-E/hqdefault_live.jpg&dashmpd=https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/dash/hfr/1/as/fmp4_audio_clear,fmp4_sd_hd_clear/source/yt_live_broadcast/key/yt6/ip/72.239.175.191/expire/1501068725/ipbits/0/signature/D9AC8668BF9CF6B884B618938C9823515B17D8F2.1FDA7E07B2B55FBCCF80C654BA9E0A1F9A48F589/playlist_type/DVR/itag/0/requiressl/yes/sparams/as,gcr,hfr,id,ip,ipbits,itag,playlist_type,requiressl,source,expire/gcr/us/id/fN2sEo7hq-E.0&ypc_ad_indicator=4&ucid=UCfiwzLy-8yKzIbsmZTzxDgw&iv_load_policy=1&iurlmaxres=https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fN2sEo7hq-E/maxresdefault_live.jpg&oid=o0grDQo8XcVLrPz5jByaaQ&iv_invideo_url=https://www.youtube.com/annotations_invideo?cap_hist=1&video_id=fN2sEo7hq-E&ei=VSl4WcedBNbjqgXe7bzQCw&cver=1.20170724&live_playback=1&fmt_list=&auth_timeout=21600000&thumbnail_url=https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fN2sEo7hq-E/default.jpg&root_ve_type=&has_cc=False&is_listed=1&url_encoded_fmt_stream_map=&fresca_module=1&enable_cardio=1&fresca_preroll=1&ypc_license_checker_module=1&iurlsd=https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fN2sEo7hq-E/sddefault_live.jpg&remarketing_url=https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/962985656/?backend=player_vars&cname=1&cver=AS3&data=backend%3Dplayer_vars%3Bcname%3D1%3Bcver%3DAS3%3Bptype%3Dview%3Btype%3Dview%3Butuid%3DfiwzLy-8yKzIbsmZTzxDgw%3Butvid%3DfN2sEo7hq-E&foc_id=fiwzLy-8yKzIbsmZTzxDgw&label=followon_view&ptype=view&delay=5&tmi=1&view_count=3025044&use_cipher_signature=False](https://s.youtube.com&title=Al+Jazeera+Arabic+Live+Stream+HD-+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%AB+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D9%8A+%D9%84%D9%82%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%A9+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%A9+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A9+%D8%A8%D8%AC%D9%88%D8%AF%D8%A9+%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%A9&ptk=aljazeera&iurl=https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fN2sEo7hq-E/hqdefault_live.jpg&vm=CAEQARgE&hlsvp=https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/hls_variant/gcr/us/signature/26ADA228BD5549EC76852E925945A6EDBD8A78A9.268E76E7A0831E0DB3C36670FCA24805B0F9AD94/requiressl/yes/source/yt_live_broadcast/key/yt6/ip/72.239.175.191/ipbits/0/maudio/1/playlist_type/DVR/itag/0/expire/1501068725/sparams/gcr,go,id,ip,ipbits,itag,maudio,playlist_type,requiressl,source,expire/go/1/id/fN2sEo7hq-E.0/file/index.m3u8&pltype=contentlive&cl=162900125&iurlmq=https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fN2sEo7hq-E/mqdefault_live.jpg&enable_cardio_before_playback=1&no_get_video_log=1&short_view_count_text=3M+views&avg_rating=4.24240619416&fexp=9422596,9431012,9434289,9441392,9446364,9449243,9457141,9460072,9461821,9463594,9464546,9465833,9466793,9466795,9466797,9466851,9467217,9468797,9468799,9468805,9471755,9475953,9477113,9477691,9478524,9478670,9480034,9480475,9480535,9480795,9481684,9482647,9483080,9484209,9484514,9484643,9484706,9485999&keywords=al+jazeera+tv,al+jazeera+Arabic,%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%B1%D9%87,%D8%A7%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1,%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%B1,free+tv+channels,aljazira,%D8%A7%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%A9,%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%83%D9%86%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A9,%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%A9+%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B1+%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B4%D8%B1,al+jazeera+english+live,aljazeera+tv+live,%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%B4,%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%82,%D8%A7%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%82,%D8%A7%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1+%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A7,%D8%AF%D9%85%D8%B4%D9%82,%D8%A7%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1+%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B1,%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A7,%D8%A8%D8%B4%D8%A7%D8%B1+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AF,%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%AC%D9%84+%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A7,%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%AC%D9%84,%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%AF,%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A9,%D9%86%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A9,%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1,%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85,%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D9%81%D8%AF,%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%A9+%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B4%D8%B1,%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D9%85%D9%87%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A9,syria+news,%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%AB+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D9%8A,%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%AB+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D9%8A+%D9%84%D9%82%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%A9+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%A9,%D8%AC%D9%88%D8%AF%D8%A9+%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%A9,hd&idpj=-4&c=WEB&innertube_client_version=1.20170718&account_playback_token=QUFFLUhqa3NJenBCUUNnZnBtMHdOb3FLSWE0cG9qQkZBZ3xBQ3Jtc0ttYkdZeEI0TExmQWo1RldLQlFZSGtLTE1wcEJGamNNZnE4UlhDaUpfRGtvSG5WbG1KUHNvbk44T2dtM2NRb0NwWmNZaU9sdGc2MTY3QUg3SldKTmtxOWNzMjVfZ0R5VDYwM1E3RDVQQnNHTU12OVphSQ==&iv3_module=1&iurlhq=https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fN2sEo7hq-E/hqdefault_live.jpg&dashmpd=https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/dash/hfr/1/as/fmp4_audio_clear,fmp4_sd_hd_clear/source/yt_live_broadcast/key/yt6/ip/72.239.175.191/expire/1501068725/ipbits/0/signature/D9AC8668BF9CF6B884B618938C9823515B17D8F2.1FDA7E07B2B55FBCCF80C654BA9E0A1F9A48F589/playlist_type/DVR/itag/0/requiressl/yes/sparams/as,gcr,hfr,id,ip,ipbits,itag,playlist_type,requiressl,source,expire/gcr/us/id/fN2sEo7hq-E.0&ypc_ad_indicator=4&ucid=UCfiwzLy-8yKzIbsmZTzxDgw&iv_load_policy=1&iurlmaxres=https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fN2sEo7hq-E/maxresdefault_live.jpg&oid=o0grDQo8XcVLrPz5jByaaQ&iv_invideo_url=https://www.youtube.com/annotations_invideo?cap_hist=1&video_id=fN2sEo7hq-E&ei=VSl4WcedBNbjqgXe7bzQCw&cver=1.20170724&live_playback=1&fmt_list=&auth_timeout=21600000&thumbnail_url=https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fN2sEo7hq-E/default.jpg&root_ve_type=&has_cc=False&is_listed=1&url_encoded_fmt_stream_map=&fresca_module=1&enable_cardio=1&fresca_preroll=1&ypc_license_checker_module=1&iurlsd=https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fN2sEo7hq-E/sddefault_live.jpg&remarketing_url=https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/962985656/?backend=player_vars&cname=1&cver=AS3&data=backend%3Dplayer_vars%3Bcname%3D1%3Bcver%3DAS3%3Bptype%3Dview%3Btype%3Dview%3Butuid%3DfiwzLy-8yKzIbsmZTzxDgw%3Butvid%3DfN2sEo7hq-E&foc_id=fiwzLy-8yKzIbsmZTzxDgw&label=followon_view&ptype=view&delay=5&tmi=1&view_count=3025044&use_cipher_signature=False)

How do I go about extracting the m3u8 url from the above string? I want it to look like this once done:

> hlsvp=https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/hls_variant/gcr/us/signature/26ADA228BD5549EC76852E925945A6EDBD8A78A9.268E76E7A0831E0DB3C36670FCA24805B0F9AD94/requiressl/yes/source/yt_live_broadcast/key/yt6/ip/72.239.175.191/ipbits/0/maudio/1/playlist_type/DVR/itag/0/expire/1501068725/sparams/gcr,go,id,ip,ipbits,itag,maudio,playlist_type,requiressl,source,expire/go/1/id/fN2sEo7hq-E.0/file/index.m3u8

I have the following code that stops at this point, as below:

```
extension ViewController {

/*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608686/how-can-i-get-the-actual-video-url-of-a-youtube-live-stream*/
func get_youtube_link(videoID: String) {

    let url: URL = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=fN2sEo7hq-E&el=info&ps=default&eurl=&gl=US&hl=en")!

    let session = URLSession.shared

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        // grab the URL returned by YouTube, which is a URL with many parameters
        let feedback = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

        // convert NSString to String
        var newString = String(feedback!)

        //https://www.uraimo.com/swiftbites/swift-url-encoding/
        newString = newString.removingPercentEncoding!
        newString = newString.replacingOccurrences(of: "%2C", with: ",")

        print(newString)


    })

    task.resume()

}
```

}

This is YouTube's web query data received in RAW format:

> partnerid=27&root_ve_type=&c=WEB&iurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FVmxIA8L3Xz8%2Fhqdefault_live.jpg&of=GC6OCn1lTVgpgJyrp2hYjw&hlsdvr=1&eventid=FEx5We_CJMut4QSH_5OYCw&ypc_license_checker_module=1&auth_timeout=21600000&videostats_playback_base_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs.youtube.com&token=WIs368zOOjdA6jb7Wo5HIeCUIjDqF6aTm40Qf9Lm8xY%3D&csn=FEx5We_CJMut4QSH_5OYCw&plid=AAVVQxkmPLDdDSm-&allow_ratings=1&live_playback=1&live_default_broadcast=1&fexp=9422596%2C9431012%2C9434289%2C9441386%2C9446364%2C9449243%2C9457141%2C9460072%2C9461821%2C9463594%2C9464546%2C9465833%2C9466793%2C9466795%2C9466797%2C9466851%2C9467217%2C9468797%2C9468799%2C9468805%2C9471755%2C9475953%2C9477113%2C9477691%2C9478524%2C9478670%2C9480034%2C9480475%2C9480535%2C9480795%2C9481684%2C9482647%2C9483080%2C9483701%2C9484209%2C9484514%2C9484643%2C9484706%2C9485999&fresca_module=1&idpj=-7&delay=5&iurlmq=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FVmxIA8L3Xz8%2Fmqdefault_live.jpg&avg_rating=4.53108348135&ypc_ad_indicator=4&remarketing_url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fpagead%2Fviewthroughconversion%2F962985656%2F%3Fbackend%3Dplayer_vars%26cname%3D1%26cver%3DAS3%26foc_id%3DSrZ3UV4jOidv8ppoVuvW9Q%26label%3Dfollowon_view%26ptype%3Dno_rmkt&innertube_client_version=1.20170718&video_verticals=%5B16%2C+396%5D&ldpj=-27&title=euronews+LIVE&tmi=1&watermark=%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fs.ytimg.com%2Fyts%2Fimg%2Fwatermark%2Fyoutube_watermark-vflHX6b6E.png%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fs.ytimg.com%2Fyts%2Fimg%2Fwatermark%2Fyoutube_hd_watermark-vflAzLcD6.png&cver=1.20170725&iv3_module=1&no_get_video_log=1&has_cc=False&thumbnail_url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FVmxIA8L3Xz8%2Fdefault.jpg&iv_invideo_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fannotations_invideo%3Fcap_hist%3D1%26video_id%3DVmxIA8L3Xz8%26ei%3DFEx5We_CJMut4QSH_5OYCw&author=euronews+%28in+English%29&status=ok&ptk=youtube_none&fresca_preroll=1&iurlsd=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FVmxIA8L3Xz8%2Fsddefault_live.jpg&length_seconds=1800&view_count=159557&is_listed=1&vm=CAEQABgE&enable_cardio_before_playback=1&dashmpd=https%3A%2F%2Fmanifest.googlevideo.com%2Fapi%2Fmanifest%2Fdash%2Fas%2Ffmp4_audio_clear%252Cfmp4_sd_hd_clear%2Fgcr%2Fus%2Fexpire%2F1501143156%2Fsignature%2F7779193FA964EC075A94C62E6720B2380AEE39A0.B546BFA286574BA5D7BE116159ACC45130650938%2Fkey%2Fyt6%2Fip%2F72.239.175.191%2Fplaylist_type%2FDVR%2Fitag%2F0%2Fipbits%2F0%2Fsource%2Fyt_live_broadcast%2Frequiressl%2Fyes%2Fhfr%2F1%2Fsparams%2Fas%252Cgcr%252Chfr%252Cid%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Cplaylist_type%252Crequiressl%252Csource%252Cexpire%2Fid%2FVmxIA8L3Xz8.0&hlsvp=https%3A%2F%2Fmanifest.googlevideo.com%2Fapi%2Fmanifest%2Fhls_variant%2Fgcr%2Fus%2Fkey%2Fyt6%2Fip%2F72.239.175.191%2Fplaylist_type%2FDVR%2Fexpire%2F1501143156%2Fitag%2F0%2Fsource%2Fyt_live_broadcast%2Fmaudio%2F1%2Fid%2FVmxIA8L3Xz8.0%2Fsparams%2Fgcr%252Cgo%252Cid%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Cmaudio%252Cplaylist_type%252Crequiressl%252Csource%252Cexpire%2Fipbits%2F0%2Fgo%2F1%2Frequiressl%2Fyes%2Fsignature%2FB225396C754E6783728F71F0C1AD4CFE9AFC3839.B2C6E2FFCB07B136D4AECFA5A8F001DFEC084543%2Ffile%2Findex.m3u8&timestamp=1501121556&iurlmaxres=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FVmxIA8L3Xz8%2Fmaxresdefault_live.jpg&use_cipher_signature=False&live_chunk_readahead=3&iv_load_policy=1&live_storyboard_spec=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fsb%2FVmxIA8L3Xz8%2Fstoryboard_live_60_3x3_b0%2FM%24M.jpg%3Frs%3DAOn4CLBjUwFPDoNQCv904oDJpmFEM5xg7g%23106%2360%233%233&ucid=UCSrZ3UV4jOidv8ppoVuvW9Q&allow_embed=1&pltype=contentugclive&short_view_count_text=159K+views&fmt_list=&keywords=&enable_cardio=1&video_id=VmxIA8L3Xz8&streaminglib_module=1&url_encoded_fmt_stream_map=&cl=162900125&account_playback_token=QUFFLUhqbl9LME8tdzdIT1VJaG1qRk1VZ3U1OFNnMW1PZ3xBQ3Jtc0ttY0dMZWZJdGtkUVNqTjlFWHpubjE2Rjg5OGxlU21fUndLa3Y0THoyMWpGa3ZXWDN2R3JkR1JHS2tEcm51OXhTbTFqYlNGTHVKY1hrOWllcFlHRU9NNHFZTjZNNGRZQjZ1eFc2VGxjMHpScWFDWnUxdw%3D%3D&muted=0&iurlhq=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FVmxIA8L3Xz8%2Fhqdefault_live.jpg

Comment: Why was my question voted down? Let me know so that I understand what I did wrong as not to repeat it. Thanks!

Comment: Most likely because your question shows no effort of any kind. There are countless examples of extracting substrings in Swift. Do some basic research. Try something. Then [edit] your question to show the code you have tried (as text, not as an image or a link) and clearly explain what you need help with.

Comment: Thank you, but I have been working on this for severa hours. I wanted the question to be basic and easy to understand. That was my mistake. I will edit as you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of `print(newString)`? Is it the first string in your original question? Is that the value where you need the leading and trailing `x`s removed? Why are there `x`'s on both ends of that string?

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect the answer to your question.

Comment: But is `newString` that giant "URL string" at the start of your question or is it something else?

Comment: Yes, the newString is that giant string block returned by YouTube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found the answer. I'll post it just incase someone needs it.

Here you go: [Extract the M3U8 video link from a YouTube live channel in Swift 3](https://gist.github.com/haalkibsi/ad52c6502a2ca0752cce0fbbc81de0bb)

I'd like to point out that Code Different's answer is more elequent than mine. Give them both a try and see what fits your project needs :)

```
//
//  EXT_youtube_JSON.swift
//  YoutubeStreamURL
//
//  Created by Haitham Alkibsi on 7/25/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Haitham Al-Kibsi. All rights reserved.
//
import Foundation

extension ViewController {

    /* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608686/how-can-i-get-the-actual-video-url-of-a-youtube-live-stream */
    func downloadJSON_youtube(videoID: String) {

        let url: URL = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=\(videoID)&el=info&ps=default&eurl=&gl=US&hl=en")!

        let session = URLSession.shared

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

            // grab the URL returned by YouTube, which has many parameters
            var youtubeReply = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!

            // remove percent encoding
            //https://www.uraimo.com/swiftbites/swift-url-encoding/
            youtubeReply = youtubeReply.removingPercentEncoding!
            youtubeReply = youtubeReply.replacingOccurrences(of: "%2C", with: ",")


            //https://www.dotnetperls.com/find-swift
            let firstResult = youtubeReply.range(of: "hlsvp=", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: youtubeReply.startIndex..<youtubeReply.endIndex, locale: nil)

            if let range = firstResult {

                // Start of range of found string.
                let start = range.lowerBound

                // Display string starting at first index.
                var firstExtraction = youtubeReply[start..<youtubeReply.endIndex]
                firstExtraction = firstExtraction.chopPrefix(6)


                let secondResult = firstExtraction.range(of: ".m3u8", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: firstExtraction.startIndex..<firstExtraction.endIndex, locale: nil)

                if let range2 = secondResult {

                    let start = range2.lowerBound

                    let secondExtraction = firstExtraction[firstExtraction.startIndex..<start]

                    let m3u8_URL = secondExtraction + ".m3u8"
                    print(m3u8_URL)
                }
            }
        })

        task.resume()

    }
}

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445917/what-is-the-most-succinct-way-to-remove-the-first-character-from-a-string-in-swi
extension String {
    func chopPrefix(_ count: Int = 1) -> String {
        return substring(from: index(startIndex, offsetBy: count))
    }

    func chopSuffix(_ count: Int = 1) -> String {
        return substring(to: index(endIndex, offsetBy: -count))
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16831120)

Comment: @Swati I have updated the answer as requested. Please remove your down vote of the answer. The way you guys moderate this community sucks and has made this experience very negative.

Comment: i havent downvoted the answer: just added a review reason. I have learnt from my experience that links dont work all the time and answers become invalid

Comment: Your code gives me a chuckle: `String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!`. Could have done that with `String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!`. Code Different's answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data is tortuously long but did not help clarify your question in any way. It's better to come up with [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Now to your question, use `URLComponents` to extract data from the URL:

```
// Assuming feedback is what you get back from YouTube
let feedback = "partnerid=27&root_ve_type=&c=WEB&iurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FVmxIA8L3Xz8%2Fhqdefault_live.jpg&of=GC6OCn1lTVgpgJyrp2hYjw&hlsdvr=1&eventid=FEx5We_CJMut4QSH_5OYCw&ypc_license_checker_module=1&auth_timeout=21600000&videostats_playback_base_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs.youtube.com&token=WIs368zOOjdA6jb7Wo5HIeCUIjDqF6aTm40Qf9Lm8xY%3D&csn=FEx5We_CJMut4QSH_5OYCw&plid=AAVVQxkmPLDdDSm-&allow_ratings=1&live_playback=1&live_default_broadcast=1&fexp=9422596%2C9431012%2C9434289%2C9441386%2C9446364%2C9449243%2C9457141%2C9460072%2C9461821%2C9463594%2C9464546%2C9465833%2C9466793%2C9466795%2C9466797%2C9466851%2C9467217%2C9468797%2C9468799%2C9468805%2C9471755%2C9475953%2C9477113%2C9477691%2C9478524%2C9478670%2C9480034%2C9480475%2C9480535%2C9480795%2C9481684%2C9482647%2C9483080%2C9483701%2C9484209%2C9484514%2C9484643%2C9484706%2C9485999&fresca_module=1&idpj=-7&delay=5&iurlmq=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FVmxIA8L3Xz8%2Fmqdefault_live.jpg&avg_rating=4.53108348135&ypc_ad_indicator=4&remarketing_url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fpagead%2Fviewthroughconversion%2F962985656%2F%3Fbackend%3Dplayer_vars%26cname%3D1%26cver%3DAS3%26foc_id%3DSrZ3UV4jOidv8ppoVuvW9Q%26label%3Dfollowon_view%26ptype%3Dno_rmkt&innertube_client_version=1.20170718&video_verticals=%5B16%2C+396%5D&ldpj=-27&title=euronews+LIVE&tmi=1&watermark=%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fs.ytimg.com%2Fyts%2Fimg%2Fwatermark%2Fyoutube_watermark-vflHX6b6E.png%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fs.ytimg.com%2Fyts%2Fimg%2Fwatermark%2Fyoutube_hd_watermark-vflAzLcD6.png&cver=1.20170725&iv3_module=1&no_get_video_log=1&has_cc=False&thumbnail_url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FVmxIA8L3Xz8%2Fdefault.jpg&iv_invideo_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fannotations_invideo%3Fcap_hist%3D1%26video_id%3DVmxIA8L3Xz8%26ei%3DFEx5We_CJMut4QSH_5OYCw&author=euronews+%28in+English%29&status=ok&ptk=youtube_none&fresca_preroll=1&iurlsd=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FVmxIA8L3Xz8%2Fsddefault_live.jpg&length_seconds=1800&view_count=159557&is_listed=1&vm=CAEQABgE&enable_cardio_before_playback=1&dashmpd=https%3A%2F%2Fmanifest.googlevideo.com%2Fapi%2Fmanifest%2Fdash%2Fas%2Ffmp4_audio_clear%252Cfmp4_sd_hd_clear%2Fgcr%2Fus%2Fexpire%2F1501143156%2Fsignature%2F7779193FA964EC075A94C62E6720B2380AEE39A0.B546BFA286574BA5D7BE116159ACC45130650938%2Fkey%2Fyt6%2Fip%2F72.239.175.191%2Fplaylist_type%2FDVR%2Fitag%2F0%2Fipbits%2F0%2Fsource%2Fyt_live_broadcast%2Frequiressl%2Fyes%2Fhfr%2F1%2Fsparams%2Fas%252Cgcr%252Chfr%252Cid%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Cplaylist_type%252Crequiressl%252Csource%252Cexpire%2Fid%2FVmxIA8L3Xz8.0&hlsvp=https%3A%2F%2Fmanifest.googlevideo.com%2Fapi%2Fmanifest%2Fhls_variant%2Fgcr%2Fus%2Fkey%2Fyt6%2Fip%2F72.239.175.191%2Fplaylist_type%2FDVR%2Fexpire%2F1501143156%2Fitag%2F0%2Fsource%2Fyt_live_broadcast%2Fmaudio%2F1%2Fid%2FVmxIA8L3Xz8.0%2Fsparams%2Fgcr%252Cgo%252Cid%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Cmaudio%252Cplaylist_type%252Crequiressl%252Csource%252Cexpire%2Fipbits%2F0%2Fgo%2F1%2Frequiressl%2Fyes%2Fsignature%2FB225396C754E6783728F71F0C1AD4CFE9AFC3839.B2C6E2FFCB07B136D4AECFA5A8F001DFEC084543%2Ffile%2Findex.m3u8&timestamp=1501121556&iurlmaxres=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FVmxIA8L3Xz8%2Fmaxresdefault_live.jpg&use_cipher_signature=False&live_chunk_readahead=3&iv_load_policy=1&live_storyboard_spec=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fsb%2FVmxIA8L3Xz8%2Fstoryboard_live_60_3x3_b0%2FM%24M.jpg%3Frs%3DAOn4CLBjUwFPDoNQCv904oDJpmFEM5xg7g%23106%2360%233%233&ucid=UCSrZ3UV4jOidv8ppoVuvW9Q&allow_embed=1&pltype=contentugclive&short_view_count_text=159K+views&fmt_list=&keywords=&enable_cardio=1&video_id=VmxIA8L3Xz8&streaminglib_module=1&url_encoded_fmt_stream_map=&cl=162900125&account_playback_token=QUFFLUhqbl9LME8tdzdIT1VJaG1qRk1VZ3U1OFNnMW1PZ3xBQ3Jtc0ttY0dMZWZJdGtkUVNqTjlFWHpubjE2Rjg5OGxlU21fUndLa3Y0THoyMWpGa3ZXWDN2R3JkR1JHS2tEcm51OXhTbTFqYlNGTHVKY1hrOWllcFlHRU9NNHFZTjZNNGRZQjZ1eFc2VGxjMHpScWFDWnUxdw%3D%3D&muted=0&iurlhq=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FVmxIA8L3Xz8%2Fhqdefault_live.jpg"
let urlString = "https://www.youtube.com?" + feedback
let components = URLComponents(string: urlString)!

if let queryItems = components.queryItems,
    let hlsvp = queryItems.first(where: { $0.name == "hlsvp" })
{
    print(hlsvp.value!)
} else {
    print("hlsvp not found")
}
```

Comment: Your answer has a URL in at, the sample data returned by YouTube is NOT a URL.. otherwise I would of used URLComponents.

Comment: What does exactly the web query return? You can always add an arbitrary domain name to it to make it a URL (it just has to be well-formed, doesn't need to be valid)

Comment: The web query returns that mega code block you hated so much :)
I added an arbitrary domain name and attempted to run your code block, but unfortunately components always returned Nil.

Comment: What is the value of `feedback`, before you percent-escape anything? Add the raw string to your question

Comment: "feedback" is that BIG yellow block I keep referring you to that is already at the top of my question.

Comment: I want the raw string, **before you percent-escape anything**. Looking at your code, that's not the case. What you showed is the variable `newString`, not `feedback`

Comment: Got it. Pasting it at the end of the question now.