# String basics with Swift

Tags: swift, string, swift3

Just trying to remove the first character from a string in Swift.  I use the code written below, but the second line keeps crashing my application.

Is this not the correct way to unwrap a String Index?  What is?

```
var tempText = text
let toRemove = tempText?.startIndex ?? String.Index(0)
tempText?.remove(at: toRemove)
```

Comment: What is the crash message? Is the string empty?

Comment: You may wish to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445917/what-is-the-most-succinct-way-to-remove-the-first-character-from-a-string-in-swi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing a `String.Index` type instead of getting the index of the `tempText` string.

Moreover, `startIndex` is not an optional, `tempText`, however, is.

You should check if `tempText` exists and is not empty (you can simply do this with an `if let`), and remove the character at `startIndex` if it matches those conditions.

```
var tempText = text

if let toRemove = tempText?.startIndex {
    tempText?.remove(at: toRemove)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this cleaned it up perfectly.  So obvious now that you explained *facepalm*

Comment: Jesus, what's with all the force unwrapping? You *already* have an if statement, just change it to a conditional binding.

Comment: @the4kman Is it really? `tempText = tempText?.characters.dropFirst().map(String.init) ?? tempText`

Comment: @the4kman Sure, but you can unwrap the string index without force unwrapping everythign else ..

Answer (score 3):

You can use Collection method dropFirst:

```
if let text = text { // you need also to unwrap your optional
    let tempText = String(text.characters.dropFirst())  // And initialize a new String with your CharacterView
}
```

In Swift 4 String conforms to Collection so you can use it directly on your string:

```
if let text = text {
    let tempText = text.dropFirst()  // "bc"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using swift 4, you can use:

```
var tempText = text.dropFirst()
```